# Handle item click in parent fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my application, I have the `Fragment` (say `ParentFragment`) which contains a `GridLayout` and I am using `GridLayoutManager` to display UI items in the grid using a `ViewHolder` and `RecyclerAdapter` class. This `GridLayout` has 2 rows and 4 columns. Data for each Grid Cell is stored in the `DataContentInformation` class which has two variables `DataHeader` and `DetailedInformation` class.

Below this `GridLayout` UI I have another `Fragment` (say `DetailedFragment`) component which should get updated based on the selection in `GridLayout`. `DataHeader` will be displayed inside the `GridLayout` cell and `DetailedInformation` will be displayed inside the `DetailedFragment`.

How I can pass the grid item click event which is inside the `GriLayout` to update the `DetailedFragment`?

Thanks in advance,

*IamHuM*

Comment: Consider editing your question to add some code snippets to make the problem more clear

Comment: You should also add a screenshot or mockup of what your app looks like. Remember a picture is worth a thousand words!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps and change the parameters and code according to your own requirements.I am just giving the steps to perform the task:

STEP 1:

In your RecyclerView Adapter,
change the constructor to something like this and pass the fragment:

```
     public TestAdapter(Context context,ParentFragment parentFragment)
     {
    this.context=context;
    this.parentFragment=parentFragment;
     }
```

STEP 2:
Add below code to onBindViewHolder() method of Recycler View

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TestHolder holder, final int position) {
    //Add other code here
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
               ((MainActivity)parentFragment.getActivity()).yourMethod();
         }
       }
   });

}
```

STEP 3:
In your Main Activity,you can add the code to update DetailedFragment somthing like below:

```
  public void yourMethod()
  {
  Fragment reference = null;
            List<Fragment> fragmentList =getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
            for (int i = 0; i < fragmentList.size(); i++) {
                reference = fragmentList.get(i);
                if (reference != null && reference instanceof DetailedFragment) {
                    ((DetailedFragment) reference).methodToUpdateDetailedFragment();
                }
            }}
 }
```

STEP 4:
Put the method to update UI of Detailed Fragment,

```
 public void methodToUpdateDetailedFragment()
   {
   //Write your code to update UI here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This [example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example) is very similar to what you are describing. Hope it helps